# How to make an image slide down

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would like to make the image in the center of the navigation bar slide down when the width of the page decreases.

This is how it looks like on a desktop:

[image]

Whereas on a smartphone the navigation bar should look like this:

[image]

As you can see, I would like the nav bar to remain as it is, except for the image to slide down the first row.

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("images/spiaggia.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

header li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

header .mobile {
  display: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("images/città.jpg");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -999999px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid lightblue;
}


/* Features */

.features {
  background: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
}

.features figure img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: gray 0 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobile {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .desktop {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="website/Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a class="logo" href="Home.html">Cadice_foto</a></li>

    <li class="mobile"><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="mobile"><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>


    <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>

</header>
<section class="features">
  <figure>
    <img src="images/porticciolo.jpg" alt="porticciolo Cadice">
    <figcaption>Porticciolo Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="images/palme.jpg" alt="palme Cadice">
    <figcaption>palme Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="images/sera.jpg" alt="sera Cadice">
    <figcaption>sera Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>


</section>
<section>lower-section</section>
<footer>Via Condotti, Roma IT - numero: 02.123456 - email@email.com</footer>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a css `flex-box`, and re-ordering the flex elements when your mobile view media query activates.

```
.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-container>* {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 20%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .menu-container>* {
    flex: 1;
    counter-increment: menulink;
    order: counter(menulink);
  }
  .menu-left {
    order: 1
  }
 .menu-right {
    order: 3
  }
  .logo-menu {
    order: 2;
 }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}

/* Header */

header {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/1000/500?image=6");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/200/100");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -999999px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid lightblue;
}

/* Features */

.features {
  background: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
}

.features figure img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: gray 0 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-container>* {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 20%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .menu-container>* {
    flex: 1;
    counter-increment: menulink;
    order: counter(menulink);
  }
  .menu-left {
    order: 1
  }
  .menu-right {
    order: 3
  }
  .logo-menu {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="11.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="menu-container">
      <a class="menu-left" href="Home.html">Home</a>
      <a  class="menu-left" href="website/Menu.html">Menu</a>
      <a  class="menu-right"href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a>
      <a  class="menu-right" href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a>
      <div class="logo-menu"><a class="logo" href="Home.html">Cadice_foto</a></div>
    </header>
    <section class="features">
      <figure>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150?image=2" alt="porticciolo Cadice">
        <figcaption>Porticciolo Cadice</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150?image=8" alt="palme Cadice">
        <figcaption>palme Cadice</figcaption>
      </figure>

      <figure>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150?image=4" alt="sera Cadice">
        <figcaption>sera Cadice</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </section>
    <section>lower-section</section>
    <footer>Via Lars, somewhere IT - numero: uno!- email@email.com</footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following in media query below in your CSS:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

You may want to know what this code does. The **position** property specifies the type of positioning used for an element. The **top** property is the vertical position of a positioned element. The **left** and the **right** properties are written to reset positioning (these are "auto" by default), and then **margin** which is "0 auto" to align element by center. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

You should probably see some info about media-queries here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

P.S. And remember **DRY** (Do not Repeat Yourself). Try to avoid writing twice, especially something like this:

```
            <li class="mobile"><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
            <li class="mobile"><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>


            <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
            <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
```

You can set every property for every element in every media-query

Answer (score 1):

I have changed your code little bit to achieve what you wanted. Here is the [Code](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/gJMwGB)

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}


/* Header */

header {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("https://www.hotelsantamargherita.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/caorle-dalla-spiaggia-di-pon-1440x500.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  height: 200px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

section {
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div {
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar li {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo a {
  background-image: url("http://www.florenceholidays.com/image/66-05.jpg");
  background-size: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid lightblue;
}


/* Features */

.features {
  background: white;
  color: gray;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.features figure {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 200px;
}

.features figure img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  box-shadow: gray 0 0 10px;
  width: 200px;
}


/* Footer */

footer {
  background: black;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%)
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="website/Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li class="logo"><a href="Home.html">Cadice_foto</a></li>
    <li><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
    <!--     <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Locations.html">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="desktop"><a href="website/Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li> -->
  </ul>
</header>

<section class="features">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="porticciolo Cadice">
    <figcaption>Porticciolo Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="palme Cadice">
    <figcaption>palme Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="sera Cadice">
    <figcaption>sera Cadice</figcaption>
  </figure>

</section>
<section>lower-section</section>
<footer>Via Condotti, Roma IT - numero: 02.123456 - email@email.com</footer>
```